# Remove TextField button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this simple code, but at this moment we only have one button, which is responsible for adding new TextField.
How can I make second button which will be responsible for removing last generated TextField? I totally have no idea.

```
import SwiftUI



struct Test : View {
    @State var ingredientNames = [""] 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack { /// vertical stack of ingredients
            ForEach(ingredientNames.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                TextField("Name", text: $ingredientNames[index])
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                ingredientNames.append("")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/removelast()

Comment: you created one button and have no idea how to add another??? although your button is with 2 images for some reason.

Comment: do you need to remove text that is typed inside textField OR remove the last text field itself?

Comment: @Yodagama remove the last text field itself

Comment: Now why post a question, get an answer and then delete it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512636/show-value-from-textfields-as-a-text-in-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the other icon into another button, and remove the last added text field by removing items off the end of the `ingredientNames`.

I also added a guard statement, so users don't accidentally delete from an empty list, which would cause an error.

```
struct Test : View {
    @State var ingredientNames = [""]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack { /// vertical stack of ingredients
            ForEach(ingredientNames.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                TextField("Name", text: $ingredientNames[index])
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                ingredientNames.append("")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                guard !ingredientNames.isEmpty else {
                    print("no items to remove")
                    return
                }
                ingredientNames.removeLast()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```